# Can a certain hypergeometric expression with complex parameters can be expressed with real parameters?

Tags: hypergeometric-function

I am working on a physics problem where the solution depends on the hypergeometric function. My solution ends up being:

$ _1F_2(1;b,b+1;z)$

where b is a complex number. I have to transform this function to a form like:

$ _1F_2(a_1;b_1,c_1;z_1)$

where a,b, and c are real numbers. I have been looking around for a useful identity but no success so for. I appreciate any comments or suggestions.

Comment: One thing that might help is that real[b]>0. I think in this limit the function might even have an analytic form

Comment: Actually z is can be expressed as -z^2.